# camera calibration with different chess board size

Tags: ros, calibration, ros-kinetic, image-pipeline, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to perform monocular camera calibration using a chessboard that has 6X6 squares in it where each square has side length as 0.054 m. The number of squares in the chessboard and side of squares are different than the example shown in http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration. My question is that can I get good calibration  with the modified chessboard that I mentioned I have been using which is different from th given example?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310549/camera-calibration-with-different-chess-board-size/) by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2018-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you should be able to use that size of chessboard with the camera calibrator by passing the `--size 5x5 --square 0.054` command line options. (5x5 because the number of crosses is one less than the number of squares)

The resulting calibration will probably be decent if each square of the chessboard appears much larger than your camera's pixel size in most of the calibration images. The checkerboard should probably fill 10-100% of the camera's field of view while calibrating.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/23020/anirban/) on 2018-12-13**:
Thank you, it helped